# How could I declare my variable C58?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I made a document for work supposed to help my everyday life. It is working Ok but I would like to add some extra features BUT I don't know much about Google scripts.

I searched on google docs help forum, read some articles on webappps.stackexchange and the Google app script guide but I don't find what I wish.

In my ideal document, a message would pop up when an item quantity goes below a certain number. In the meantime, an email would be sent to my email address (and maybe another one)saying that it is time to order the specific item.

Ok I try!

```
if(C58<=15)
{ 
          window.alert(We are close to run out of bags);

          MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com",
                   "Bags order",
                   "We are close to run out of bags");
 }
    else
    {} 
    }
```

How could I imbricate all this together? Could someone help?

Comment: The question is too broad. Do you already know how to read a cell value?

Comment: What do you mean? I entered the script but it does not work. Mistake on the window.alert sentence "missing )"

Comment: Questions on this site should be about a specific feature or problem but the question title looks to be asking three questions, 1) how to show a pop-up, 2) how to evaluate a condition and 3) how to send an email. By the other hand the code in the question is not complete as it's not enough to declare a function; `C58` it's a valid variable name but it's not declared.

Comment: Considering the above, I'm wondering if you know, by using Google Apps Script, how to read a cell value.

Comment: Changed the title ;)

Comment: I guess that I do not know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the variable C58 should have the value of cell C58 from the active sheet, the following script will show an alert showing a message that includes the value of that variable.

```
function myFunction(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var C58 = sheet.getRange('C58').getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('The value of C58 is ' + C58);
}
```

For details regarding how to create a Google Sheets script see [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
I still have a pb with the same line : window.alert(We are close to run out of bags); though
Will read and try to understand a bit how it works :)

Comment: @Karlraki : Bear in mind that Google Apps Script runs on the server so client-side objects like window aren't available.

Comment: Let's forget about the window.I manage to send an email from the sheet but the script doesnt take the number of bags into consideration. I would like this email to be sent only when the number of bags (C58) equals/goes below 15

Comment: @Karlraki : Please update your question to show your progress and what you tried.